# Bone moves one part of mesh but not the other

Tags: mesh, bones

When I move the bone of the leg it moves everything except[image] for the straps on the boot, I checked the weight and it was at 1. It's very odd because the straps are attached to the boot.[image](someone said to put a screenshot of the "N" panel.

Comment: Does it happen on both sides? Is there maybe a mirror modifier involved?

Comment: I have already applied the mirror modifier, that shouldn't be it

Comment: In edit mode, select a vertex of a strip and take a screenshot of the "N" properties panel, vertex weight tab, or upload your file.

Comment: You didn't include Vertex Weight rollout into the screenshot of the N panel.

Comment: I do not see an area for weight for some reason